# Openvpn Access Server hosting a web server as vpn client. Port forwarding, IPTables, and Firewall? How to

Tags: networking, openvpn, webserver, nginx, amazon-web-services

**ENVIRONMENT:**

I have successfully set up a LEMP email/webserver running off of my home IP address, with my domains dns pointing to my home IP. My server is behind a firewall router, which is behind my ISP router. I believe this would be called a double NAT setup. To get all of the email/web server ports working, I had to forward port 443, port 80, and the corresponding email server ports, from my 'ISP router' to my 'firewall router', then, forward those same ports from my 'firewall router' to my 'LEMP Webserver'.

**THE PROBLEM:**

My issues is that my home IP is a not a static IP, so I cannot set the proper Reverse DNS and PTR records for the email server. In an attempt to solve this, I have created a cloud AWS Openvpn Access Server EC2 Instance, and have assigned it an elastic IP, which now has the proper PTR and reverse DNS records for my server.

**THE GOAL:**

The idea, was to tunnel the webserver as a client to the AWS EC2 Openvpn Access Server instance for the sole purpose of using and AWS IP address, DNS address, and setting the proper PTR Records on amazons elastic IP's settings. The desired outcome for all of this, would be that my dns records for my website [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) point to Amazon's IP address, instead of my home address, resulting in my websites ip address being that of Amazon's IP, as opposed to my Home IP.

**STEPS I HAVE TAKEN:**

1. So far, I have installed openvpn client on my webserver, and successfully tunneled it to amazons AWS EC2 OpenVPN Access Server, using openvpnclient on the webserver/email server. There are currently no DNS leaks on my webserver, and my public ip address and DNS address on the web server both point to Amazon's corresponding public IP and DNS.
2. I have changed my DNS records on domain registrars website, to point to the newly created AMAZON OpenvpnAS Public IP address.
3. I have opened all webserver (443,80) ports and email server (25,993,etc.) ports using UFW on the EC2 Instance.

**THE QUESTION:**

With all of the above settings set, My webserver/email server is still innaccessable when going to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com). Now that my my server is being successfully tunneled as a client to the OpenVPNAS, and the DNS records are pointing to the EC2 IP address, WHAT ELSE MUST I DO IN ORDER TO GET MY EMAIL SERVER/WEBSERVER TO PROPERLY RESOLVE THROUGH THE OPENVPN TUNNEL?

Should I be forwarding ports from the ec2 instance public IP to the vpn client, and if so, how exactly do I do such a thing on an openvpnas instance?

Answer (score -1):

The best solution for your issue is DynDNS (dyn.com). In this case, you don't need OpenVPN.

You will need to install their client on your machine. This client keeps the DNS updated every time your IP address changes.

Make sure your TTL is set to the minimum value.

Comment: That isn't even remotely a solution. That DOES NOT, give me a static ip address with a proper reverse DNS and PTR, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: https://help.dyn.com/setting-up-reverse-dns/

Comment: I'm quite aware of what dynamic dns is. But it still doesn't allow me to get my PTR records. Thanks for the help, but again, this is not a relevant answer.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't help.